# How to create a preference that accepts only integer values

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-preferences

Is there a way to create a preference in a *PreferenceFragment* that accepts only integer values? I could implement an *EditTextPreference* and register an *OnPreferenceChangeListener* in which I could reject the change if the user enters a a string that is not a number, but I would prefer something that is meant for holding only numbers and that does not allow users to enter anything else, maybe showing only a dial pad keyboard.. I don't such a preference exist, since every descendant of *Preference* is mapped onto a Boolean (*CheckBoxPreference*), a String (*EditTextPreference) or a String array (*MultiSelectListPreference*), i.e. there are no preferences mapped onto integers, but maybe some of you can give me an hint or at least tell me if there are better solutions than the one I've proposed above.

**Solution proposed by Grey:**

```
EditText editText = ((EditTextPreference)    
                             findPreference("intent_property")).getEditText();
editText.setKeyListener(new NumberKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public int getInputType() {
        // The following shows the standard keyboard but switches to the view 
        // with numbers on available on the top line of chars
        return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;
        // Return the following to show a dialpad as the one shown when entering phone
        // numbers.
        // return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE
    }

    @Override
    protected char[] getAcceptedChars() {
        return new String("1234567890").toCharArray();
    }
});
```

Shorter solution, which does not allow varying the keyboard to dialpad but requires less code:

```
EditText editText = ((EditTextPreference) 
                             findPreference("intent_property")).getEditText();
editText.setKeyListener(new DigitsKeyListener());
```

I don't like just one thing about this solution: the user can enter 0000 and it is accepted and saved in the shared preference (which is a String) as "0000".. this requires you to implement a OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener to intercept changes to shared preferences and remove leading zeros in this preference or implement a change listener directly on this preference and return false to refuse numbers with trailing zeros (**tell me if there is a better solution to this last problem which does not involve implementing your own Preference**). It would be beautiful if we could modify the *newValue* in *OnPreferenceChangeListener*..

Comment: How about you take [the source of `EditTextPreference`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/preference/EditTextPreference.java#EditTextPreference) as starting point and swap out all string-related methods for their int-based counterparts? Seems pretty straightforward to me. Also, since then you'll have direct access to the `EditText` object, you can set any numbers-only input type to your liking.

Comment: @MH It seems straightforward if I manage preferences programmatically, but then if I create an *EditTextIntegerPreference*, for example, I can't use it in the XML file I pass to the *PreferenceFragment*, or is there a way to register a new XML tag that maps onto my new object?

Comment: You can use custom preferences in xml files in the same way you do with custom views. Just provide the fully qualified class name; e.g. `com.costanzi.gianni.example.ExamplePreference`. For an example, see [this API demo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/xml/advanced_preferences.html).

Comment: Thank you for writing this. It gave me some clue as to what to do with my EditTextPreference. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading the proposed solutions, I still think a custom preference is the way to go. I did read your remark in bold text, but setting up a basic `EditTextIntegerPreference` is actually super simple and it will solve the remaining issue you have when the user enters for example "0000".

Just a note up front: since you normally want to be able to use preferences in several places in your app, as far as I'm concerned, a proper implementation of an `EditTextIntegerPreference` would store its value against an `Integer`. That way you'll be able to retrieve the int value anywhere, without the need to first parse or cast it.

However, to keep this answer to the point and compact, I'm actually going to show an extension of a regular `EditTextPreference`, which means that under the hood, the value will still be stored as a string. If you're really keen on getting the 'proper' implementation to work, I don't mind writing that up later on. It shouldn't be too tricky though, so you might want to have a crack at it yourself first. :)

```
public class EditTextIntegerPreference extends EditTextPreference {

    private Integer mInteger;

    public EditTextIntegerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        getEditText().setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
    }

    public EditTextIntegerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        getEditText().setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
    }

    public EditTextIntegerPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getEditText().setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
    }

    @Override public void setText(String text) {
        final boolean wasBlocking = shouldDisableDependents();
        mInteger = parseInteger(text);
        persistString(mInteger != null ? mInteger.toString() : null);
        final boolean isBlocking = shouldDisableDependents(); 
        if (isBlocking != wasBlocking) notifyDependencyChange(isBlocking);
    }

    @Override public String getText() {
        return mInteger != null ? mInteger.toString() : null;
    }

    private static Integer parseInteger(String text) {
        try { return Integer.parseInt(text); }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) { return null; }
    }    
}
```

The reason why this solves the "0000" issue, is that we're simply casting the user typed value to an int before we store it, and plug it back into a string upon retrieval. That means any leading zeroes (except for '0' as a number of course) will automagically disappear.

The 'number' input type will restrict the user to input only enter numbers, so the `parseInteger(...)` method is mainly present for sanity reasons, although it will catch a `NumberFormatException` if you try to enter an empty or `null` string. Again, you can make this more pretty, which I haven't done for now.

Comment: Many many many thanks to you for the time you've spent for me, your example is very clear.. I found quite strange that they didn't provide an attribute for such a preference in order to say "it must accept only numbers and in that case it must be saved onto an Integer/Float", but implementing a solution like yours is not too heavy.. another possible solution is to listen to property changes and when that property changes, take the string value and cast on an integer (which removes leading zeros), since I'm sure it will contain only numbers.

Comment: @Gianni Costanzi: Regarding the other possible solution you mention: that's definitely true, although the advantage of having a dedicated preference class for that is that the logic is nicely self-contained and abstracted from other, non-related code. It all works the same though, so up to you. :)

Comment: You're perfectly right, IMHO, your solution is better since self-contained.. Thanks

Answer (score 32):

There is an easier way to do this. Just set in the EditTextPreference in your XML to android:numeric="integer" (you can set it to integer, signed or decimal).

Eclipse (or whatever tool you are working in) won't show you this as a possible attribute, but just write it in your EditTextPreference and clean your project. You will see that it won't give you any errors. :)

Answer (score 1):

i guess u can call getEditText() to get a EditText obj , then call setKeyListener with a  NumberKeyListener.

Comment: I'll try this as soon as I can, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I've tried what you told me and it works flawlessly, look at the main post in which I've added the piece of code. Again, many thanks!

Comment: If you have further suggestion about the code written above, you're welcome!

Comment: I'm sorry for the many comments, but 5 minutes editing time is too short for me :-/ Why do I need to add a *NumberKeyListener* and then still have to specify I want only numbers?I could also return letters as *accepted characters* in my *NumberKeyListener* and it would not complain, so I don't clearly understand why there is a *Text* and a *Numeric* *KeyListener*, what is the difference? Are they doing some work under-the-cover which differs between them two? **EDIT**: Maybe I must use a direct subclass like *DigitsKeyListener* and not the *NumberKeyListener*, right?

Comment: i think what u r suggesting is right.  let say someone use digitsKeyListener which accpet (- .), but  he intends to use only (1-9) then he can not use digitskeylisente. but fall back to NumberKyeLisetner, and give specified char set. but if you dont mind with "negtive sign or dot" you can use it as this. Or you want to limit to only 1-3 u have only to use NumberKeylisenter only right?

Comment: What you say can be better implemented with the *DigitKeyListener* returned by *DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(true,true)*, which automatically allows for a sign (only at the beginning) and for a dot (only once). I wonder why they did not add a flag to avoid also zeros at the beginning (allowing for only a single zero if followed by the dot for decimals). In case you want to allow only a subset of digits, as you say, I think the right way to go is using a *NumberKeyListener*.

Answer (score 1):

You should use PreferenceActivity which is basically used to show preferences like an xml file. In this activity you can use checkboxes, edit text and save values to preferences.

Comment: Can you provide an example snippet for the OP?

Answer (score 0):

You can also reopen the dialog when you get an exception after trying to parseInt() the number.
Here is a sample code:

```
public class MyEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference {

        private EditText _editText;

        public MyEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            _editText = getEditText();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

            super.onDismiss(dialog);

            try {
                Integer.parseInt(_editText.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                ((Dialog) dialog).show();
            }
        }
    }
```